# Trying to update laravel 5.1 to 5.2 gives error requirments could not resolve

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am trying to update an 3 year old project made in laravel 5.1.
I am following the update guide from the laravel documentations. 
When I run `composer update` I get the following error:

[image]

This is what my `composer.json` looks like:

```html
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "bican/roles": "2.1.*",
        "tymon/jwt-auth": "0.5.*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "0.6.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-snappy": "^0.3.0",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "h4cc/wkhtmltoimage-amd64": "0.12.x",
        "itsgoingd/clockwork": "^1.11",
        "predis/predis": "^1.1",
        "witty/laravel-push-notification": "1.0.0",
        "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "~1",
     "zjango/laracurl": "dev-master",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.2",
     "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
        "mollie/mollie-api-php": "1.9.*",
        "mollie/laravel-mollie": "^1.5",
        "tom-lingham/searchy" : "2.*",
        "oprudkyi/laravel-mail-logger": "^1.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "lesstif/php-jira-rest-client": "^1.19"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
        "laracasts/generators": "^1.1",
        "diablomedia/phpunit-pretty-printer": "^1.0",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "~3.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "~3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php",
            "tests/TestCaseModel.php",
            "tests/TestCaseController.php",
            "tests/TestCaseImageController.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

How do I fix this? 
To update my laravel project.

Besides that is there any easy way to update all my packages to a compatible version for laravel 5.2?

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to share error messages. This prevents the system to search for similar questions and prevents me from Googling the message.

Answer (score 0):

Library witty/laravel-push-notification is too old to install Laravel in version 5.2. One of dependencies of laravel-push-notification is illuminate/support in version "5.0.* | 5.1.*".

You're trying to install Laravel 5.2 but that library needs Laravel 5.1 to works.

PS Maybe it will help you
1) `rm -rf composer.lock vendor`
2) `composer install`